# How can I copy entire chain of text messages (not just a single one) with the stock Android messages app?

Tags: sms, google-messages, export

How can I copy or export an entire chain of text messages (not just a single one) with the stock Android messages app? This is needed for a claim.

I know I can screenshot stuff, but the date for older messages is missing. I know I can long press on a single message to select it.
I can long press on multiple messages.
But that's beside the point: how can I grab the data --- message, date & time received?

If it's relevant, the phone is Pixel 4a.

Comment: Referring to the title. note that Android doesn't have *the* stock messaging app, instead each manufacturer may use their own messaging apps. For example: Google Nexus and Pixel series use Google Messages, while Samsung uses Samsung Messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stock SMS app on Pixel 4a does not have this option and you need alternative methods.

Use [SMS Backup and restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore)

- **Option 1** : Take a complete backup of your SMSes and from the app see "Backed up (time)" and tap *view details*. It will list SMS Backup. Tap on that to *view conversations* and all your conversations are listed. From the 3 dots menu against the conversation you want select *print conversation* and it will be printed as a PDF file with date and time stamps. Example below (You can get sent and received. I chose a conversation that doesn’t reveal personal details). From the pdf you can copy and paste wherever needed.

[image]

- **Option 2**: From settings → backup settings → selected conversations only, choose the conversation you want and repeat steps in Option 1 to get a print, share or copy to clipboard.

I am not affiliated  to this app but it's likely the best of it's kind.

Comment: Just tried this on your recommendation, and it worked. The export format took a little work to extract the simple text, but I was able to do this with a modern text editor.