# Where is the saved .vzm file?

Tags: sms, verizon, message+

I am trying to save text messages for a particular caller.

In the Message+ app, in the "Conversations" window I long press on the caller and select Save messages. The next window "Save Conversations" shows a default file name (which I can change if so desired). Then I click Save and that window closes and it returns to the Conversations window.

If I long click again and go to "Save Conversations" it shows the file I save (see screenshot).

I want to know where this file is on the filesystem or be able to send that file in an email. As it is, I can only Restore, which is not what I need.

[image: Screenshot]

Looking in the file browser, I do not see this file in Downloads, or anywhere.

Mobile service is Xfinity/Verizon. I called them and they were not able to help

Device: Pixel 6a
Android version: 14

Comment: Please also link the app, so that future readers can know which is the app you are referring to//From the context and tags I could figure out that it is from Verizon (and therefore not shown in Play Store for me, since Verizon doesn't operate in India)

Comment: I rolled back the edit because the screenshot isn't related to the original issue. Instead, I've edited one of your comments on the answer to include the link to the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if the file is saved in app directory, it may not be accessible to you unless your device is rooted

Since Verizon isn't helping you, you may like to explore a third party solution as explained in my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241975/131553)

To summarize :

1. Install [SMS Backup and restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) and take a back up of your SMSes.
2. > From the app see "Backed up (time)" and tap *view details*. It will list SMS Backup. Tap on that to *view conversations* and all your conversations are listed. From the 3 dots menu against the conversation you want select *print conversation* and it will be printed as a PDF file with date and time stamps. It will show both sent and received SMSes.
3. Send the PDF file by mail.

Comment: Just a note. The first week of this app if free. After that it is $13 per WEEK which is outrageous.

Comment: Look at the [FAQ](https://www.synctech.com.au/sms-backup-restore/sms-faqs/) for the difference between ordinary and paid version//I have got the ordinary version running for years and this answer is based on that!

Comment: The free version has ads while the paid does not.//
The paid version has options to compress and encrypt the backup files.//
The paid version has support for using WebDAV as a cloud location for backups.// None of these are required for the answer I wrote// Even the pro one costs less than $ 6 as a one time buy //IDK what figures you are quoting// [Link to the paid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestorePro)

Comment: I've added a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVliz.png) of the renewal notice

Comment: @AlLelopath sorry logged in after a long while, maybe it's a region specific thing, I understand developers can do that(I am not one)